# .load dosen't work after page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this 2 pages in jquery mobile:

Home - http://snipt.org/zixj3

Inner - http://snipt.org/ziya9

you can see the live here: [www.leoferrari.com/congresso1/](http://www.leoferrari.com/congresso1/)

I use:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", ".jqm-demos", function() {
 $("#menu").load('menu.html', function() {
  $(this).trigger("create");
 });

 $("#footer").load('footer.html', function() {
  $(this).trigger("create");
 });
});
```

to load menu and footer, but when i click to go to the inner page the footer and menu dont load, if a reload the page the footer and menu load normally

Comment: Try `trigger('pagecreate')` and instead of `pageinit` use `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: not work, i try @Omar

Comment: First of all, add the following to your `<head>` remove the old links, they r for demo purposes only. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />`
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok, Alredy done.
Nothing Happened.